# Why am I getting Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range?

Tags: arrays, swift

// Declare an empty array
var generatedCards = Card

```
    // Array to keep track of numbers generated
    var intArray = [Int]()
    
    // Randomly generate 8 pairs of cards
    while generatedCards.count < 8 {
        
        // Generate a random number
        let randNum = Int.random(in: 1...13)
        intArray.append(randNum)
        
        for index in intArray {
            if intArray.count == 0 {
                print("Array is empty")
            } else if intArray.count > 0 {
                if intArray[index] == randNum {
                    print("There is a match, do nothing")
                } else {
                    // Create two new card object
                    let cardOne = Card()
                    let cardTwo = Card()
                    
                    // Set their image names
                    cardOne.imageName = "card\(randNum)"
                    cardTwo.imageName = "card\(randNum)"
                    
                    // Add them to the array
                    generatedCards.append(cardOne)
                    generatedCards.append(cardTwo)
                    
                    print(randNum)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am confused as to why I keep getting an index out of range? I am comparing the size of the array to make sure it is not empty before I compare the values inside with the random number. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which line causes the crash? What are the different values when this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect the code to do, but here is what it is doing:

You generate a random number and put it in the intArray. Then you loop over the intArray and use the content of the intArray to compare the random number with the content of the first index number of the intArray. If the intArray is only 1 element, but the random number is bigger, you get the error. The chance that the first number in the intArray is bigger than 0 is 12/13.

You should not write:

```
for index in intArray {
....
}
```

Since this gives you the content of the intArray. I think you want to loop over the intArray like this:

```
for index in 0..<intArray.count {
    if intArray[index] == randnum ....
}
```

Your code will then work.

Comment: Better yet, maybe `for index in intArray.indices`